# How to avoid invalid certificate warnings when browsing to my custom local HTTPS server?

Tags: windows, ssl

What I'm doing: running a simple HTTPS server in my PC, browsing to localhost, and trying to avoid the warning by installing a temporary certificate.

The following code is based on what I found in this example of the QtHttpServer library:
https://github.com/qt-labs/qthttpserver/blob/master/tests/auto/qhttpserver/tst_qhttpserver.cpp

The library was built and tested with no problems.

This is my code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtHttpServer/QtHttpServer>

static const char g_privateKey[] = R"(-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----)";

static const char g_certificate[] = R"(-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----)";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QHttpServer httpServer;

    httpServer.route("/", []() { return "Hello world"; });

    httpServer.sslSetup(QSslCertificate(g_certificate),
                        QSslKey(g_privateKey, QSsl::Rsa));

    if (httpServer.listen(QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"),443)) {
        qDebug() << "Server started";
        return a.exec();
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Server failed to start";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The Private Key and Certificate values were copied literally from the QtHttpServer example.

The server starts, and I'm able to browse to localhost (*or qhttpsservertest.com, which I've created an alias for in the etc file just to be sure it matches the cert's CN*).

However, as expected, a warning is shown and I need to confirm before actually browsing anything.

I know I can add a trusted certificate in the OS (Windows in my case). Other programs, like Fiddler or Burp Suite need something similar to work transparently with the browsers.

But I don't know what to do here. I just copied the certificate content in a .cert file, and successfully imported it with *certmgr* but I keep getting the same warnings when I browse to my custom server. Why?

***-- EDIT --***

It seems this has nothing to do with Qt or QtHttpServer.

I tested the certificate with **Nginx**, and still getting the same browser warning (*ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID*).

FYI, the nginx.conf file:

```
# ...
http {
    # ...
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  qhttpsservertest.com;
        ssl_certificate     qhttpsservertest.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key qhttpsservertest.key;
        # ...
    }
    # ...
}
```

This opens the question to a more general public.

What kind of manipulation I need to do in my system to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: What is your warning message exactly?

Comment: @Le Ngoc Thuong

It says, no matter the browser, "Your connection isn't private...blah blah blah...NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID".

And instead of the padlock icon in the address bar, I get "not secure". Clicking on that shows "Certificate (not valid)".

Comment: Maybe you should try to generate a cert by yourself.

Comment: @Le Ngoc Thuong I did that, with OpenSSL.
In fact, that was the first thing I did, before using the QtHttpServer example's.

Comment: Did you try to add the cert into trusted root?

Comment: Yes, with certmgr. I mentioned that.

Comment: Yeah, I've read it but you didn't mention that where you installed it, just to make sure. By the way,  I have no idea about your issue. I use to be code with self-signed cert but it is always ok. Sorry that I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I found a concise step-by-step guide [here](https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/).

I was ignoring the first two steps. I was adding the signed certificate to Trusted Root.

I hope this question helps another newbie in the future.